# I want to sort a array on the given sub string bases

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

my vales are like.

```
array("app_text_music" , "app_text_ball" , "app_text_cat")
```

i want to sort this array data on the bases of music,ball and cat.
how i can do it ? please suggest me. when i use asort it only see first   character of array.

```
asort(array("app_text_music" , "app_text_ball" , "app_text_cat"));
```

how to sort this type of array values. 
i want to get the above substring like car, ball or music and sort on the base of that category.

Comment: sort() function is your friend - http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: is the "app_text_" prefix  constant or subject to any change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really sort on the base of your prefix,
you need to perform your own sorting function.

You'll be able to do that using user defined function
with [usort()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php)

But, otherwise, just sort() is sufficient.

```
<?php
$test =
[
    "app_text_music",
    "app_text_ball",
    "app_text_cat",
    "app_media_dog",
    "app_media_book"
];

usort($test, function($a, $b)
{
    $a = array_pop(explode('_', $a));
    $b = array_pop(explode('_', $b));

    return (strcasecmp($a, $b));
});


// This will output :

array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "app_text_ball"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "app_media_book"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "app_text_cat"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "app_media_dog"
  [4]=>
  string(14) "app_text_music"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

asort sorts based on index, and you are using the array without indexes. in your case you can just use sort() :)

```
$test = array("app_text_music" , "app_text_ball" , "app_text_cat");

sort($test);
```

Comment: but i want to sort the array on the bases of app_text_(that element) ?

Comment: because whole array elements are prefixed by app_text_(...), sort() is correct. then, if the prefix "app_text_" is cauded to change... the sort that how you describe have not sense..

Comment: EDIT: may be looking for ursort() to make your functional sort ? http://php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php